# MGF of Generalised Itô Integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, itos-lemma

The following derivation produces a moment closure problem - I would appreciate any insight. It may seem trivial at first glance, but the key aspect is the integrand dependence on $t$.

Consider $W_t$ to be a typical Brownian motion. Introduce the process

$$
X_t = \int\limits_0^t dW_s G_{s-t}
$$

where $G_0=1$, and $\mathbb{E}[G_t]=G_t$, which implies $dG_t \sim dt$. The moments of $X_t$ (up to a reasonable order) can be found explicitly (**EDIT** this is only true under a linear homogeneous response $G_t$). To determine the MGF, define

$$
Y_t = e^{\lambda X_t}
$$

such that the MGF of $X_t$ is $M_t^{\lambda} = \mathbb{E}[Y_t]$. Using Itô's lemma

$$
dY_t = \left[ \lambda dW_t+\lambda\int\limits_0^t dW_s dG_{s-t}+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}dt\right] Y_t
$$

Taking the expectation gives

$$
d\mathbb{E}[Y_t] = \lambda\int\limits_0^t \mathbb{E}[dW_s Y_t] dG_{s-t}+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}dt\mathbb{E}[Y_t]
$$

Independence of increment does not appear to admit further simplification.
Under the simplifying assumption, $dG_t = G_t dt$, this becomes

$$
d\mathbb{E}[Y_t] = -\lambda d t\mathbb{E}[X_t Y_t]+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}dt\mathbb{E}[Y_t]
$$

which presents a moment closure problem.
I realise that the MGF of $e^{\lambda G_t X_t}$ can be found explicitly, and that arguments of the $X_t$ distribution can be made accordingly, but is it possible to calculate $M_t^{\lambda}$ directly using only Itô's lemma?

**Addendum**:
Having examined the process again, it appears that applying the power series of the exponential is the most direct way of calculating the MGF.

Furthermore, the assertion $dG_t = \alpha dt G_t$ is required in order to obtain closure. For more general response (Green's) functions, the process must be constructed as

$$
X_t = \int\limits_0^{t} dW_s \frac{G_s}{G_t}
$$

where closure can be obtained even if $G_t$ does not satisfy a first-order linear homogeneous differential.